# Solr Facet with date gap and other facet field

Tags: solr

I've been doing a lot of researching within the Solr Docs especially around faceting. In Solr 6.3+, is it possible to facet on a date gap by day (or any other gap) and another field? A simple yet contrived example:

```
Blue
     1/1/2017 : 25
     1/2/2017 : 23
     1/3/2017 : 62
Red
     1/1/2017 : 12
     1/2/2017 : 73
     1/3/2017 : 82
Yellow
     1/1/2017 : 83
     1/2/2017 : 64
     1/3/2017 : 42
```

I've looked into facet intervals/dates/ranges/groupings but none seem to quite fit.

This seems like a very common use case and I'd be surprised to know it's not currently possible. To my knowledge, facet queries are used only to select certain facet values, not actually facet based on specific indexed field values.

Comment: so, you want something like nested facets?

Comment: Yes, however nesting it this way doesn't work when specifying a date gap. @Mysterion

Comment: cause basic gap faceting working just fine

Comment: Can you provide an example? This produces a non-nested facet when doing `facet=true&facet.field=color&facet.field=date&facet.gap=+1DAY`

Comment: sorry, i mean non-nested facet with gap is working for me just fine, not the same for you?

Comment: Can you provide an example? The above query is returning two separate facet counts. Not a hierarchical count as shown in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134021/discussion-between-mysterion-and-bdeo).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, maybe json faceting might be what you ar looking for  ? http://yonik.com/multi-select-faceting/

Comment: @jagguli I haven’t. Faceting is the key I think but trying to do a range facet and a regular facet doesn’t merge the results as I’d hope and no range query doesn’t let me specify a gap (+1DAY). Maybe I’m doing it wrong but that is my understanding.